# Youtube iframe nocookie not working. Trying to send me cookies

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

```
<iframe 
                            width="100%" 
                            height="315" 
                            src={`https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/${props.ModalData.id}`} 
                            title="YouTube video player" 
                            frameBorder="0" 
                            allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" 
                            allowFullScreen>
                        </iframe>
```

my code is like this. the video opens. but i am getting errors in console. regarding the cookie and cors policy.

[image]

[www.youtube-nocookie.com](http://www.youtube-nocookie.com) I tried with but still getting these errors.

errors:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://play.google.com/log?format=json&hasfast=true&authuser=0' from
> origin 'https://www.youtube-nocookie.com' has been blocked by CORS
> policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control
> check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value
> 'http://play.google.com' that is not equal to the supplied origin.

> POST https://play.google.com/log?format=json&hasfast=true&authuser=0
> net::ERR_FAILED

> Indicate whether a cookie is intended to be set in a cross-site
> context by specifying its SameSite attribute

Forget the 'mixed' error. i fixed it. but other errors remain

Comment: See this [ticket on Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/229013699) - vote for that ticket in order to get more attention from YouTube developers.